# Xcode call application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am integrating application A to application B. Is that any way I can call the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` of AAppDelegate of application A from application B??

Comment: Please tell us why you wish to do this.. Maybe it isn't necessary. And as ElanthiraiyanS said.. your app might get rejected.. and a rejected app is no app.

Comment: i am actually integrate the sms application into a chat application. The chat application will have 5 tabs and the 1st tab is "sms". I wish to call the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions from SMSAppDelegate so that it would init the other controller when user tap the sms tab.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to launch one application from another,

You could use a **Custom URL scheme** to launch one application from another. But it is not legal and your app will get rejected by apple.

Have a look at this link,

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Answer (score 0):

Why would you check if a standard app is launched? The SMS app is always running and therefor the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method will never get called for the sms app.
Maybe this tutorial will help you reach your goal. Please tell me if it's totally NOT what your looking for, because maybe i'm just misunderstanding you a.t.m.

http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-how-to-send-in-app-sms/

p.s. documentation from Apple can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the needed controllers and views to the "new" app and integrate it there. You shouldn´t change things about the application lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

calling `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` can be used if at some point you want to restart your application from the beginning. I am very late but it might help other to solve their problems.
 below code will help you in this.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            [appDelegate application:[UIApplication sharedApplication] didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:nil];
```